# Inserting at position in List

Tags: scala

This insert function is taken from :

http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p21.scala

```
  def insertAt[A](e: A, n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[A] = ls.splitAt(n) match {
    case (pre, post) => pre ::: e :: post
  }
```

I want to insert an element at every second element of a List so I use :

```
 val sl = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")          //> sl  : List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  insertAt("'a", 2, insertAt("'a", 4, sl))        //> res0: List[String] = List(1, 2, 'a, 3, 4, 'a, 5)
```

This is a very basic implementation, I want to use one of the functional constructs. I think I need
to use a foldLeft ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the list into Lists of size 2, then combine those into lists separated by the separation character:

```
  val sl = List("1","2","3","4","5")              //> sl  : List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  val grouped = sl grouped(2) toList              //> grouped  : List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5))
  val separatedList = grouped flatMap (_ :+ "a")  //> separatedList  : <error> = List(1, 2, a, 3, 4, a, 5, a)
```

**Edit**
Just saw that my solution has a trailing token that isn't in the question.  To get rid of that do a length check:

```
  val separatedList2 = grouped flatMap (l => if(l.length == 2) l :+ "a" else l)
                        //> separatedList2  : <error> = List(1, 2, a, 3, 4, a, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use sliding:

```
val sl = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")   

def insertEvery(n:Int, el:String, sl:List[String]) =
   sl.sliding(2, 2).foldRight(List.empty[String])( (xs, acc) => if(xs.length == n)xs:::el::acc else xs:::acc)

insertEvery(2,"x",sl) // res1: List[String] = List(1, 2, x, 3, 4, x, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `insertAt`, use pure foldLeft:

```
def insertAtEvery[A](e: A, n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[A] = 
  ls.foldLeft[(Int, List[A])]((0, List.empty)) {
    case ((pos, result), elem) =>
      ((pos + 1) % n, if (pos == n - 1) e :: elem :: result else elem :: result)
  }._2.reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion and pattern matching are functional constructs. Insert the new `elem` by pattern matching on the output of `splitAt` then recurse with the remaining input. Seems easier to read but I'm not satisfied with the type signature for this one.

```
def insertEvery(xs: List[Any], n: Int, elem: String):List[Any] = xs.splitAt(n) match {
  case (xs, List()) => if(xs.size >= n) xs ++ elem else xs
  case (xs, ys) => xs ++ elem ++ insertEvery(ys, n, elem)
}
```

Sample runs.

```
scala> val xs = List("1","2","3","4","5")
xs: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> insertEvery(xs, 1, "a")
res1: List[Any] = List(1, a, 2, a, 3, a, 4, a, 5, a)

scala> insertEvery(xs, 2, "a")
res2: List[Any] = List(1, 2, a, 3, 4, a, 5)

scala> insertEvery(xs, 3, "a")
res3: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, a, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation using recursion:

**Note** `n` must smaller than the `size` of `List`, or else an `Exception` would be raised.

```
scala> def insertAt[A](e: A, n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[A] = n match {
     |   case 0 => e :: ls
     |   case _ => ls.head :: insertAt(e, n-1, ls.tail)
     | }
insertAt: [A](e: A, n: Int, ls: List[A])List[A]


scala> insertAt("'a", 2, List("1", "2", "3", "4"))
res0: List[String] = List(1, 2, 'a, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider indexing list positions with `zipWithIndex`, and so

```
sl.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case(v,i) => if (i % 2 == 0) List(v) else List(v,"a") }
```

Comment: how many intermediate lists did we generate here? N/2? sounds slow.